# How to undo a git merge squash?

Tags: git, version-control, git-merge

I have just done a

```
git merge --squash feature-branch
```

into my `develop` branch.

The problem is that the above command updated the head without creating a new commit. My intention was to create one single commit to apply to the head of `develop`.

So in short, the log for the `develop` branch before and after the merge are exactly the same.

Is there a way to revert back `develop` to what it was before the `git merge`?

Thank you.

***Solution***

Based on the comment from Dan D. and the accepted answer below I was able to resolve my problem. See below what I did in case you are in the same boat:

1 - I ran `git reflog` and it listed all the commits and checkouts I did with my `develop` branch.

2 - Instead of doing a `git reset HEAD@{1}` as suggested, I found the number when I did the last commit to develop that I wanted to keep. In my case it was `HEAD@{188}`. So I typed `git reset HEAD@{188}`.

3 - I ran a `git log` and it had a clean log showing only the commits I had before I did the wrong merge.

4 - I ran `git add -A .` to stage all the new files created during my feature development.

5 - I ran `git commit -m "install feature-x"`

6 - As a result now I have branch `develop` with the correct files and the log is clean - showing only one commit for all the changes I did during the development of `feature-x`.

I still need to find out why my original `git merge --squash feature-branch` did not work as intended.

***Solution 2***

Mark Longair's answer is a definitive solution to my problem. I have just tested it and it works. See below the process I am using now to squash all the internal commits within a `feature-branch` and include just one commit to the `develop` branch:

```
git checkout develop
git merge --squash feature-branch
git commit -m "install of feature-branch"
```

The above sequence works like a charm.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

If you run `git merge --squash <other-branch>` the working tree and index are updated with what the result of the merge would be, but it doesn't create the commit.  All you need to do is to run:

```
git commit
```

However, if you change your mind before committing and just want to abort the merge, you can simply run:

```
git reset --merge
```

You don't need to use the reflog.

Comment: Uau, thank you. I am working in a new feature branch and I will test your suggestion to see if it works. I will update this question with the results. Thank you.

Comment: Just tested and it works. Thank you Mark. I have just updated my question with your answer.

Comment: +1 Another thinko ironed-out. Thx! (on a slightly frustrated note: this is because in git all subcommands behave slightly inconsistently - merge, stash apply, checkout with local changes, all behave differently. Not to mention the plethora of `git checkout HEAD --` vs. `git checkout HEAD -- .`, `git rebase --abort`, but not `git merge --abort`, `git push --all`, but not `git pull --all` and many subtle instances like that :))

Comment: @sehe: yes, I know what you mean - git is so elegant right up to the invocation at the command line...

Comment: ` git reset --merge` do not cleanup conflicts, so we have to run `git clean -f -d` to remove all conflict files

Answer (score 0):

If you change your mind before committing, you have these options:

Abort the merge with modern git syntax:

```
git merge --abort
```

And with older syntax:

```
git reset --merge
```

And really old-school:

```
git reset --hard
```

But actually, it is worth noticing that `git merge --abort` is only equivalent to `git reset --merge` given that `MERGE_HEAD` is present. This can be read in the git help for merge command.

```
git merge --abort is equivalent to git reset --merge when MERGE_HEAD is present.
```

After a failed merge, when there is no `MERGE_HEAD`, the failed merge can be undone with `git reset --merge` but not necessarily with `git merge --abort`, **so they are not only old and new syntax for the same thing**. Personally I find `git reset --merge` much more useful in everyday work.

Comment: `git merge --abort` didn't works for `--squash` option, so there no choice